# How to use microsoft visual studio as default text editor in Active-hdl

Tags: visual-studio-code, active-hdl

I want to change default editor in Active-hdl to microsoft visual studio and every time I click on file in Active-hdl, vs-code open that file,How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open preferences from `Tools > preferences` Then go to `Tools > File Tools`

add vs_code like this picture 
[image: this picture]

1. add 'click here to add new tool' and add new tool
2. in command add the path of your vs_code `C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe`
3. in arguments put `$(filename)`